# Enable Replication on two Compose for MySQL instances?

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, replication

I'm using IBM Cloud Services, and I've created a Compose for MySQL service instance, and I can see it has 2 access portals. Both on the same location as the server (let's say US West).

I want to create a new instance, on another location (f.e Us East), and apply Replication Master-Slave configuration, so my first service act as a Master, and the second as a Slave.

As this services runs in the cloud, I can't reach configuration files, like `my.ini` files.

I've tried configuring '`server-id`' global variable, from CLI as it's explained on MySQL Documentation but an error request me to have **SUPER** privileges (using 'admin' user). Running `GRANT SUPER on mydb TO admin@.....`, throws 'Access denied' error.

I suppose admin user given, isn't allowed to modifiy global variables.

Is there a chance of making this viable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some IBM consulting, their response:

> Out-of-the-box, **I don't think that's achievable with Compose for MySQL on the IBM Cloud**. In addition, we don't permit customer configuration changes such as the one you are asking about. Is this what you are attempting to do? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.CrossRegion.html
>
> Note that Compose for MySQL is still a beta product and is not recommended for production type data/use cases. Please see:
>
> https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/compose-for-mysql (the information at the top left)
>
> http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/pdf/6605-14/$file/i126-6605-14_08-2018_en_US.pdf (see section 3 on Service Level Agreements)